# Number of partitions in decreasing order

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, analytic-combinatorics

I want to find out the number of partitions which are strictly in decreasing order.

Eg. Partition of 4 is :

```
4
3 1
2 1 1
1 1 1 1
```

Here there's only one partition {3, 1} which is in strictly decreasing order, call this function `f`.I am interested in `f(200)`

I tried to list all possible partitions and search for the one which are in decreasing order, but it's too slow to work. I believe there is some analytical combinatorics that I'm missing.

Comment: I would have thought that the first partition on your list, 4, would also be considered to be in strictly decreasing order.

Comment: @paw88789 for simplicity, just ignore the first number i.e. the number itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly decreasing order means that the parts are all different.
Then the generating function of this sequence is
$$F(x)=\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}(1+x^k).$$
Now $f(200)+1$ (you ignore the number itself) is the coefficient of $x^{200}$ in $F$, but don't see an easy way to find it by hand.

P.S. Maple says that $[x^{200}]F(x)=487067746$.

Comment: It is also the number of partitions of $200$ with odd parts.

Comment: @Robert that works flawlessly, but can you tell me how did you arrive at this generating function

Comment: @Mayur Kulkarni This is a classic. See for example here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54961/the-number-of-partitions-of-n-into-distinct-parts-equals-the-number-of-partiti