# Geometric Progression and Counting Partitions

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, infinite-product, geometric-progressions

**Related with [The number of partitions of $n$ into distinct parts equals the number of partitions of $n$ into odd parts](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/54976/285940)**

I know that ${(x^n-1)\over (x-1)}=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+...$ as a Geometric Progress, but I do not see how
$${1\over (1-x)(1-x^3)(1-x^5)\cdot\dots}=(1+x+x^{1+1}+\dots)(1+x^3+x^{3+3}+\dots)(1+x^5+\dots).$$
can anyone please explain?

Comment: If you have the same linked question, then you could have added a comment on the answer to seek further clarification. If you have a specific question, go ahead and ask that, but fix the title of your post. Also learn [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: OK Thanks: point taken.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is why $1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+...=\frac{1}{1-x}$

You know that ${x^n-1\over x-1}=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+...+x^{n-1}$

${(x^n-1)\over (x-1)}=\frac{x^n}{x-1}-\frac{1}{x-1}$

Let $n\to \infty$ and $-1<x<1$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x^n}{x-1}-\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{x-1}=0-\frac{1}{x-1}=\frac{1}{1-x}$$

If you substitute $x$ by $u^3$ or $u^5$ you´ll get similar results.

Comment: OK so there is the implication that $$ lim_{n\to \infty}$$ and $$-1&lt;x&lt;1$$

Comment: @ArtorVrontayeus Yes, you are right.

Comment: Answer accepted with thanks. ( I do not know how else to give credit to callculus and Shagnic)

Comment: @ArtorVrontayeus You only can accept the answer. Maybe you can vote up the answer as well. Shagnic does not get directly some points. But for a couple of edits Shagnic will receive some credits.