# Bijection Partition identity

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

Hello I have a doubt about the next partition identities

$P(n: even \; number \; of \; odd \; parts)=P(n: distinct\; parts, \; number \; of \; odd\;  parts\;  is\; even)$

Also for the case when both instances of "even"  are changed to odd.

I need to show a bijection of but I can't figure out how. I have been trying with one example (n=6) to see any particular characteristic however I can not have the equality.

I trying to solve the problem by using a bijection between the partitions of each side because I am not allowed to use function now.

So, any  hint would be appreciated!

Comment: If $n$ is even, then all its partitions have an even number of odd parts.  Therefore your identity as written would reduce to $P(n) = P(n: distinct parts)$, which is not true.

Comment: When you say $P(n:\text{even number of odd parts})$, I believe what you mean to say is $P(n:\text{even number of parts, and all parts are odd})$. As written, it sounds like $P(n:\text{even number of odd parts, any number of even parts})$

Comment: And I guess when I chance "even" with  "odd" I will have the same  answer. I would like to know why in this website https://oeis.org/wiki/Partition_identities is like an identity. That is confusing.

Comment: Here is a bijection: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/54961/177399 I do not understand what you are asking in your last comment.